# Charset/Encoding Latin Character

Tags: encoding, latin, charset

I am having problems reading txt files with column headings with Latin characters, such as: "ç".

My command used is:

spark_read_csv (sc = sc, path = "txtfile", charset = "latin1", name = "mydata", delimiter = ";", header = T)

When I look at mydata, the columns come out as follows:

- "Município" => "MunicApio"
- "Vínculo_Ativo" => "VAnculo_Ativo"

Comment: Maybe what you are reading is not Latin1.

Comment: Can you provide the hex of the data?

Comment: It is not Latin1, but I cannot find out what could be the original file. Try to decode byte per byte the wrong text, and add the numeric values in the question. Or think who created the file (period or time, operating system), so that we may also check specific encodings.

Comment: Yes, is latin1. In 2016 I used SparkR directly on R, I didn't use Sparklyr. In that time, I opened the columns with their real names. The command used was read.df

Comment: I'd guess at some kind of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): UTF-8  byte sequence for `í` _Latin Small Letter I With Acute_ is `\xC3\xAD`; interpreting them as `latin-1` we get `Ã` _Latin Capital Letter A With Tilde_  and (choked down) _Soft Hyphen_ (no clue where the tilde gone away). Maybe extending a [mcve] for more character transformation could help (e.g. as `ç` =>  `Ã§`?)